# ietester? site looks very stretched?

Tags: internet-explorer

anybody ever used ietester to test their websites again multitple versions of ie? well, I downloaded it, but the site looks stretched on all versions of ie, a little less stretched on newer versions.  Even stackoverflow.com looks funny (for all versions). I do have ie8 installed, and both of the sites (stackoverflow.com and the other one) look fine on ie8. Anybody faced something similar? I didn't change any settings on ietester.

(Also, I need to actually test website functionality, not just see how it looks, so please don't suggest any screenshot things. I would really not like the option of virtualization of OS either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those multiple side-by-side IE testing programs are not reliable.

You should use the [Microsoft App Compat VHDs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) (which are free).